# python Dictionary key error

Tags: python, python-2.7

Unable to retrieve value for a key which exists in the dictionary.

Check the images ,I am not sure what I am doing wrong

[screenshot of  dictionary key and value image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8BZX.jpg)

[screenshot of error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfsCv.png)

```
frontend_ips = {};
frontend_ips['0'] = "localhost"
frontend_ips['1'] = "localhost"
frontend_ips['2'] = "localhost"


final_resp = frontend_ips['resp']
```

throws error where resp value is 1

Comment: Please put your question, code, and error messages inside the actual question body rather than links, especially mangled links.

Comment: Dude, delete this question and do new post with the code.

Comment: @Milor123 Did you check the images ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove ' ' from your resp, it should be

```
frontend_ips[resp]
```

otherwise resp is treated as string, not a variable.

plus, your keys are actually strings, while resp is integer so do either

```
frontend_ips[1] = 'something'
```

or

```
frontend_ips[str(resp)]
```

Comment: nope , doesnt work check it here http://s32.postimg.org/wzgobkq51/dictionary4.png

Answer (score 1):

if your dictionary is like this

```
>>> frontend_ips={'0':"localhost",'1':"localhost",'2':"localhost"}
```

you will get a key error if you ask for

```
>>> frontend_ips[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    frontend_ips[1]
KeyError: 1
```

but you get the correct one if you ask for

```
>>> frontend_ips['1']
'localhost'
```

the reason is simple, `1` is a number (type int) and `'1'` is a string (type str). Even if the look the same they are different data structure, therefore they are different